# Erronous Declaration when getting method from AST

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to get the Declaration of methods using AST, so I can traverse it, looking for certain statements. It worked before, but I can't get it to work anymore, the Declaration I'm getting looks to me like there's some kind of parsing error. I cannot find information on how to fix this:

```
{<|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|,compilationUnit([],[],src=|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(0,30,<1,0>,<2,2>),decl=|java+compilationUnit:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|,messages=[error("Syntax error on token \"void\", @ expected",|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(7,4,<1,0>,<1,0>)),error("Syntax error, insert \"enum Identifier\" to complete EnumHeader",|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(23,1,<1,0>,<1,0>))])>}
```

My (partial) code is as follows:

```
public rel[loc, loc] getMethods(M3 model) {
    return { <x,y> | <x,y> <- model.containment
               , x.scheme=="java+class"
               , y.scheme=="java+method" || y.scheme=="java+constructor" 
               };
}

public rel[loc, Declaration] getMethodLocWithDeclaration(M3 model) {
    rel[loc, loc] methods = getMethods(model);
    rel[loc, Declaration] methodsWithAST = {};
    for(<loc c, loc m> <- methods) {
        methodsWithAST += <m, createAstFromFile(m, false)>;
    }

    return methodsWithAST;
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createAstFromFile` function will return "half" an AST even if there is a parse error in the input file. So you get an `compilationUnit` node, but immediately below it there is an `error` node which contains the information about the parse error.

The top `compilationUnit` node also seems to have a field `messages` which lists all the errors of the current file.

There are two parse errors that the Java compiler found in that particular file:

1. `error("Syntax error on token \"void\", @ expected",|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(7,4,<1,0>,<1,0>))`
2. `error("Syntax error, insert \"enum Identifier\" to complete EnumHeader",|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(23,1,<1,0>,<1,0>))])`

To fix this, I'd open the MetricsTest class in Eclipse and use the editor support to fix the file. When the file is fixed and you try the createAstFromFile function again, it should work again.

One way to make sure you know what you are exactly parsing, is to use the `readFile` function from the IO library. It could very well be that you are sending only a part of a file to the java parser, and it can only handle full files.

If you'd add this to your for-loop, you could detect if that is the case:

```
println("Parsing \'<readFile(m)>\'");
```

It's likely you are passing this: `|java+method:///MetricsTest/testMethod()|(23,1,<1,0>,<1,0>))` as the URI to createAstFromFile, and that is only part of the `MetricsTest.java` file. I'm guessing this is what goes wrong.

To fix that, you can look up the real source location from the `decls` relation in an M3 model, and then use `.top` to cover the whole file. An alternative is to construct a `java+compilationUnit` URI for the `MetricsTest` class and give that to the `createAstFromFile` function, or look that one up from the `containment` relation.

Comment: You are exactly right in that I was parsing the method. I have a feeling that worked before, but I was probably parsing the whole file in that case. I need to only look at the particular method. What would work for that?

Comment: First parse the whole file and then find the method in there using a visit or a / deep match

Comment: Is there no substitution for the getMethodASTEclipse method?

Comment: No there isn't. Haven't thought how to do that robustly for all situations yet. If you have an idea, I'm all ears.

Comment: I can imagine. I've come so far that I now visit a whole file AST and try to match the \constructor and \method matches to the M3 method location. Do you know of a robust way to do this?

Comment: I'd use the `.decl` field on the method ast node, it should be the same as the one you are searching for.

Comment: What we should come up with for the library is the most general method of zooming out from a method uri to a compilatiobUnit URi. But you could take the easiest thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was creating an AST per file, visiting that AST and whenever I found a constructor or method add the impl to a list. For this list, I found out that I can just use the src to find the actual **loc** with which I can do whatever I want. In my case, this would be counting the LoC.

```
public list[Statement] getMethodStatements(M3 model) {
    list[Statement] methodStatements = [];

    for(file <- files(model.containment)) {
        Declaration fileAST = createAstFromFile(file, false);

        visit(fileAST) {
            case \constructor(_,_,_,impl): {
                methodStatements += impl;
            }
            case \method(_,_,_,_,impl): {
                methodStatements += impl;
            }
        }
    }

    return methodStatements;
}
```